# TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined " in d3 js on MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, d3.js

Why I am getting error on below code in place of  **data.forEach**
I added D3 js as well but code is not able to identified the "data.forEach".please let me know how to resolve this issue on MVC razor.

my data2.csv is below

```
date,close
1971,0.357
1972,1.927
1973,1.870
1974,2.014
1975,10.995
1976,16.227
1977,16.643
1978,20.644
1979,22.478
```

my scripts is below

```
       var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.close); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("data2.csv", function (error, data)
    {
        data.forEach(function (d)
        {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.close; }));

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("million Sm3");

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `parseDate`, the function "prepared" by d3, expects to be passed a string for parsing. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769923/parsedate-d3-time-formaty-not-working).

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem loading the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above, it has to do with the parsing of the date and perhaps with the loading of the csv, as Lars suspects. In any case, [here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4fQV/) after changing the csv to a javascript variable.

```
data.forEach(function (d)
    {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());
        d.close = +d.close;
    });
```