# D3 graph not loading.. Showing blank page D3.Js and python

Tags: python, json, d3.js

I am new to D3js and python. I am trying to load data from postgresql and pass the JSON to D3js and draw a line chart. I am receiving error

```
  <anonymous> hello:61
  d3.json/<() d3.v2.js:2950
  ready() d3.v2.js:2940
  d3.xhr/req.onreadystatechange().
```

Below is my D3 js call.

```
d3.json ("http://104.131.191.213/books/",function (error,data) {
if (error) return console.error(error);
console.log(data);
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.year = parseDate(d.year.toString);
d.buys = +d.buys;
});
```

My parsedate function below:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y").parse;
```

JSON:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "buys": 5841, 
  "year": "1986"
}, 
{
  "buys": 54, 
  "year": "1954"
}, 
{
  "buys": 176, 
  "year": "1967"
}, 
{
  "buys": 9389, 
  "year": "1991"
},
```

My full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
meta charset="utf-8">
<title> flask+D3 hello </title>
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
.x.axis path {
display: none;
}

.line {
fill: none;
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
 .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
 .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.buys); });

var svg=d3.select ("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    d3.json ("http://104.131.191.213/books/",function (error,data) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
      console.log(data);
      data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = parseDate(d.year.toString);
      d.buys = +d.buys;
    });
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.buys; }));

   svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y",6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Price ($)");

   svg.append("path")
     .datum(data)
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", line);

      });

    </script>
```

May i know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

from [d3.parseDate Error cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425252/d3-parsedate-error-cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined):

> d3.json(url[, callback])
>
> Creates a request for the JSON file at the specified url with the mime
>   type "application/json". If a callback is specified, the request is
>   immediately issued with the GET method, and the callback will be
>   invoked asynchronously when the file is loaded or the request fails;
>   the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the
>   parsed JSON. **The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs.** If no
>   callback is specified, the returned request can be issued using
>   xhr.get or similar, and handled using xhr.on.

so print the error and double check the url.

Comment: Hi. I printed the error and changed the URL. Still the page is not loading. I am getting a different error. Have updated the thread above. Pls assist