# how to create a time scale in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new on d3,and I'm trying to create a time scale on the x-axis starting from this csv file

`Anno,Italia
2003,46.9
2004,46.3
2005,54.0
2006,56.7
2007,56.9
2008,58.1
2009,59.0
2010,61.3
2011,62.6
2012,64.5
2013,67.2`
but when I apply the d3.time.scale(),I get on the x-axis values such as .003,.004.What can I do to obtain 2003,2004 etc. on the axis?Here's my code :

```
 var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);
 d3.csv("resources/diffusionesitiweb10anni.csv",function(data){
    dataset = data;
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){
                return d["Anno"];
          }));
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: You need to parse the date, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769923/parsedate-d3-time-formaty-not-working